# Disable controls from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms. One is MainForm which is an MDI parent and has a ToolStripFile that is set to `enabled = false` at the MainForm load, and the other form is form2 which is an MDI child and serves as my login form. If login is successful, the ToolStripFile should be `enabled = true`. I have this code but it doesn't work:

```
        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainForm mf = new MainForm();
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Username = @Username AND Passcode = @Passcode";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passcode", txtPassword.Text);

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }

            if (count == 1)
            {
                Employees emp = new Employees();
                //emp.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
                //emp.Show();
                mf.ToolStripFile.enabled = true;
                this.Dispose();
            }
            if (count > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is a duplicate in username and password.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex, "LOGIN");
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you getting exactly from the execution of this code? What doesn't work exaclty? Is `mf` even shown? (I don't see `mf.Show()`)

Comment: You disable a newly created MainForm, which cannot work. Instead, you should pass a reference to your initial MainForm into "form2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of your main form. You actually need to use the instance of the current form using `MDIParent` property.

You can use something like this in parent form:

```
        public bool EnableButton
        {
            set
            {
                button1.Enabled = value;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;

            MDIChild child = new MDIChild();
            child.MdiParent = this;
            child.Show();
        }
```

In your child form, you can do something like this:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // if successful
            (MdiParent as MDIParent).EnableButton = true;
        }
```

Comment: the MDIChild child = new MDIChild(); Is this a new class or is this a built in class? MDIChild is not showing in the intellisence of VS only MdiChildren and MdiClient. Could you please carify.

Comment: Yessss! Thanks danish. It took me a while figuring out what you meant to tell me but it was worth it!